# SQL regex with ¶ sign

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I need to write a SQL statement to find matching tags. The problem is, that in the database column the words are stored like this:

`¶Klimawandel¶Ökosystem¶Moose¶CO2¶Stickstoffkreislauf¶`

So if I want to find the word `reis` and in one column is the word `Stickstoffkreislauf` it will match, because `reis` is part of `Stickstoffkreislauf`.

Therefore I want to write a regex to match the 3 cases:

- starts with `¶`
- ends with `¶`
- starts and ends with `¶`

But unfortunately I have no idea where to start with the regex because of the `¶` in the database. Does anyone have an idea how to start this? Thank you!

Here is my statement so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT csia.cID, csia.ak_tags, p.cParentID, cv.cvName 
FROM CollectionSearchIndexAttributes csia 
JOIN Pages p ON csia.cID = p.cID 
JOIN CollectionVersions cv ON csia.cID = cv.cID 
WHERE cv.cvisApproved = '1' 
AND csia.ak_tags like '%reis%'
```

The column I'm looking for is `csia.ak_tags`.

¶ is unicode 00B6

Comment: which rdbms are you using?

Comment: i didn't find any differences in your 3rd and above two cases.

Comment: @Andreas we use MyISAM

Comment: @AvinashRaj yes, the last case would be sufficient for this example. But I'm thinking about what happens when in one column there is no `¶` at the beginning or ending of the data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13287145/mysql-querying-for-unicode-entities may be of help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try a like clause akin to this:

```
csia.ak_tags like '%\\\\u00B6reis\\\\u00B6%'
```

untested, but feels like it may work. If you get this going, adjusting for a missing trailing ¶ or a missing leading ¶ is a non-issue.

---

update:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2269/33/0

```
select * from csia
where ak_tags like concat('%',0xC2B6,'reis',0xC2B6,'%');
```

comments in [Unicode escape sequence in command line MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462939/unicode-escape-sequence-in-command-line-mysql) were helpful

---

update #2, turns out we were just looking for newlines:

```
select * from CollectionSearchIndexAttributes
where ak_tags like '%\nreis\n%';
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02f3a/3/0

Comment: can you confirm the unicode value fields are delimited with? I was guessing 00B6, but I might be wrong.  Also, what collation is the column/table under?

Comment: the collation is `utf8_general_ci`

Comment: and I'm sorry, I'm not quite sure what you mean with `can you confirm the unicode value fields are delimited with?`. Can you paraphrase that? Thank you!

Comment: the `¶` symbol is being used to delimit tags in the ak_tags field. Is your `¶` \u00B6 or some other unicode char that looks the same but has a different code?

Comment: perhaps this char code tool will help: http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html

Comment: this gives me (with prefix enabled) `U+0020 : SPACE`. But when I exchanged `u00B6` with `U+0020` or `0020` it didn't work either.

Comment: And when I var_dump the column it's displayed as a paragraph, not a space (each word is in its own row).

Comment: I think we need to actually see what data is in that column. Can you make an sqlfiddle with a couple rows of data?

Comment: from that sqlfiddle, it looks like we're looking for newline chars. updated you post. will update my answer.

Comment: You are awesome, that's it! Thank you very much for staying with me on this one!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the literal character? Sql is pretty amazing and using `like '%reis%¶'` should do the trick. Check out this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02f4d/4) that I made for testing purposes.